# How to use intent according to the position in the recyler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
private class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,  null);
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.icon.setImageResource(iconImg[position]);
            holder.nmWebsite.setText(nmWebsite[position]);
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {}
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return nmWebsite.length;
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView icon;
            TextView nmWebsite;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                nmWebsite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Web);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can u explain properly..what is your requirement?

Comment: what is this code about, what is wrong with it, and what exactly do you want?

Comment: You have `final int position`. Use it to do whatever depending on the position.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getAdapterPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()) method to from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class to get the position. Implement `itemView` `ClickListener` in `ViewHolder` class.

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView nmWebsite;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            nmWebsite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Web);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                if(position== 0){
                  //.................
                }else if(position == 1){
                  //.................
                }
                 //.......................
              }
            });
        }
    }
```